# Pass content of ts variable in js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was wondering if it's possible to use the content of a `ts` variable and use it in `js` file ?
I'm feeling trapped now I realize that I don't know how can I achieve it.

Please send me any suggestion easy to implement if possible.

My **ts** file with the `printedOption` that I want to use in my `js` file.
The content of this variable is the value of my select input.

```
 validateLuggages() {
      this.printedOption = this.selectedOption;
      this.http.get(`/routes/luggages`)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.parsedForLuggages = data;
     })
      return this.printedOption;
}
```

Now, How can I create the instance and use this variable in my `JS` file ?

Comment: Not understood your issue here. but `ts` is a `superset` of `javascript`. That means javascript is valid in `typescript` code.

Comment: Sorry for the explaination. I mean I already store a data in my .ts file in the variable printedOption. But I'm wondering how can I use this variable in a .js file.. Does it make sense ? If not I can show you more code to understand

Comment: So if I  guess, you have a set of `typescript` & `javascript` files in your code ? if so, you want to pass data to `js`.  In such case , you can either use `customEvents` to pass data & listen to get it. OR not a recommended way but you can store in global `window` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: I take `validateLuggages` is a method of a class. What is your file structure? I mean what JS file wants to use that class?

Answer (score 0):

To use any typescript variable inside javascript code you may firstly export the variable in typescript file which you want to use in the js file.

Then, you can simply use the import statement and import the variable from the correct path.

You can check the example below and refer the link for better clarity. [LINK](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/import+ts+in+js+file)

// Add to tsconfig.json:

{
"compilerOptions": {
...
"allowJs": true
...
}
}

import MyModule from './../pages/MyModule';

Comment: The ask is about `runtime` data as given in the example.

Comment: hello thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure to understand.. What is my module ? It's my ts file where my variable is stored?

Comment: Module is nothing but just an example, you can export the variable from ts file you want to use and then import the same in your js file.